# Django project is very slow

Tags: python, django, performance

I have a problem with my Django project. 
Currently I'm using Django 1.6, Python 3.3.3 sorl-thumbnail 12.0 and everything is really slow. I've spent the last 3 days in attempts to change it, but everything that I've tried, has had a very minor effect. Below are the numbers from the django-debug-toolbar:

```
User CPU time - 1976.123 msec
System CPU time - 176.011 msec
Total CPU time - 2152.134 msec
Elapsed time - 3671.669 msec

SQL - 25.95 ms (62 queries)
CACHE - 76 in 7.409811019897461 ms
Haystack query - 0.031ms
```

And the time, needed for the code in the view to be executed is 0.04816937446594238. The result was calculated in the following way:

```
import time
...
def base(request):
    start_time = time.time()
    #do something
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time - start_time)
    return render(request, 'service/service.html', { 'services': services })
```

Can you please give me some advice on this? The db, static files, media files and elasticsearch are installed on my local machine. The DEBUG flag is True.

Edit 1: According to Tommaso answer, I have measured the time, needed for template rendering, and the result was awful - 3407.9 ms (using template_timings_panel for django_debug_toolbar). Also when I make a test with ab, on the same page, the time is not very different compared to the number above. Is it normal? What I can do to optimize it?

Comment: _"The DEBUG flag is True"_ - this is your problem. DEBUG turns on a lot of performance reducing caching start by turning this off.

Comment: the problem is clearly in the render part (which for some reason you are not measuring) can you add the template here?

Comment: There is something in your template that is making it very slow. We can't know why, with the current information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. on production server, static fils would be served by nginx (or similar).
2. thumbnails via SORL would be also updated once per image/size, then nginx serving
3. you gonna have cached views/calculations via memcache
4. your code would be compiled only once per session start, other calls would be much faster.

Comment: I'm giving this a +1 because it's correct but could you elaborate further some of the things/steps you'd take. That would help not only the OP but also anyone who might read this at a later date.